# Capture the Very Last Change of a Binding in SwiftUI / Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, onchange, combine

When I have a Binding in SwiftUI and I want to save whenever the binding changes I do (e.g. on a TextField)

```
var myText: String { /* value is derived */ }
func save(_ text: String) { /* doing the save stuff */ }
TextFiel(text: .init(get: { myText }, set: { save($0) })
```

Doing this, `save()` gets called whenever the binding changes. In some cases this might not be ideal, e.g. when save() makes a server call or some expensive computations.  So what I'm looking for, is to get notified whenever the **binding** changes for the *last time*.
Maybe some kind of delayed observer that fires x seconds after the final change and get's invalidated if another change happens earlier than that threshold. Does Combine offer something like this?

**Disclaimer**: This question is about bindings in general and not just about TextFields in particular. The Textfield is only a coding example , so `.onCommit` is not the solution I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debounce` operator in Combine does this. It waits until a new value hasn't been pushed through the pipeline for X amount of time and then sends a signal.

In the case of a `TextField`, you'll still want a "normal" binding, because you'd want the user to see the characters appearing in real-time even if the data doesn't get sent to the server (or whatever other expensive operation) immediately.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var text : String = ""
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        $text
            .debounce(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { (newValue) in
                //do expensive operation
                print(newValue)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $vm.text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Depending on what your operation does, you may also want to add a `.receive(on:)` operator. To update the UI, you'd want to receive on the main thread. But, for other expensive operations, you can send things to a background queue this way.

Comment: debounce is 100% what I was looking for. Thx!